# How to predict input probability of image using trained model in Keras?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I'm beginning ML and have come to a huge road bump, looked at this thing for hours. I want to get the predict() probability as output but the predictions are only outputting [[1.]] for every test image. Using larger numbers of training data and more epochs, the acc and validation acc are up to about 90% each. This is only binary classification but I don't want predict_classes. I have no idea why it's printing [[1.]]

Here is the code I'm using:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers import Activation, Dropout, Flatten, Dense
from keras import backend as K

img_width, img_height = 150, 150

train_data_dir = 'D:\Machine_Learning\\train'
validation_data_dir = 'D:\Machine_Learning\\test'
nb_train_samples = 20000
nb_validation_samples = 7000
epochs = 50
batch_size = 40

if K.image_data_format() == 'channels_first':
    input_shape = (3, img_width, img_height)
else:
    input_shape = (img_width, img_height, 3)

# Build model structure
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape=input_shape))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(64))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))



model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

# Image augmentation
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1. / 255,
    shear_range=0.2,
    zoom_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True)

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    train_data_dir,
    target_size=(img_width, img_height),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='binary')

validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    validation_data_dir,
    target_size=(img_width, img_height),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='binary')

model.fit_generator(
    train_generator,
    steps_per_epoch=nb_train_samples // batch_size,
    epochs=epochs,
    validation_data=validation_generator,
    validation_steps=nb_validation_samples // batch_size)

model.save('first_try.h5')
model.save_weights('my_weights.model')
```

And for predictions:

```
from keras.models import load_model
from keras.preprocessing import image
model = load_model('first_try.h5')

def prepare(image):
    imageSize = 150
    #imageArray = cv2.imread(filePath)
    newImageArray = cv2.resize(image, (imageSize, imageSize))
    return newImageArray.reshape(-1, imageSize, imageSize, 3)

for i in range(len(test_images)):
    print(test_images[i])
    im = prepare(test_images[i])
    prediction = model.predict([im])
    print(prediction)
```

Comment: You aren't normalizing the images the same way ImageDataGenerator does, by dividing all pixels by 255

Comment: Have you tried model.predict_proba(im)?

Comment: @heenabawa I have tried predict_proba - but from what I've read, predict() and proba() produce the same result. predict_classes() is the once that differs.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro how would I fix this -- what code would I use? I'm assuming it would go in the prepare function, but I don't know how to normalize like the ImageDataGenerator uses :rescale = 1. /255